# Unhandled Exception in Dart

Tags: dart

I've written a webserver in Dart and have a question regarding exceptions. In my HttpServer requesthandler I've added a try-catch block around the entire method:

```
try{
 ...
} catch(e) {
 ...
}
```

So I expected that this would prevent any client request from crashing the webserver. The problem is that it **can** crash when certain exceptions are thrown from within this block (heavily nested in other modules, but still initiated from this block). The following is an example of such a exception:

```
Unhandled exception:
FutureUnhandledException: exception while executing Future
  Illegal argument(s)
original stack trace:
  #0      _StringBase._createFromCodePoints (dart:core-patch:1403:3)
  #1      _StringBase.createFromCharCodes (dart:core-patch:1400:33)
  #2      String.String.fromCharCodes (dart:core-patch:1788:43)
  #3      _StringDecoderBase.decoded (dart:io:6485:12)
  #4      _File.readAsString.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:1307:29)
  #5      _FutureImpl.transform.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:881:37)

 #0      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:844:11)
 #1      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
 #2      _FutureImpl._setException (bootstrap:873:14)
 #3      _CompleterImpl.completeException (bootstrap:948:30)
 #4      _FutureImpl.transform.<anonymous closure> (bootstrap:884:36)
 #5      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:840:19)
 #6      _FutureImpl._complete (bootstrap:848:5)
 #7      _FutureImpl._setValue (bootstrap:862:14)
 #8      _CompleterImpl.complete (bootstrap:945:26)
 #9      _File.readAsBytes.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:1281:25)
 #10     _BaseDataInputStream._checkScheduleCallbacks.issueCloseCallback (dart:io:6345:59)
 #11     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6918:28)
 #12     _Timer._createTimerHandler._handleTimeout (dart:io:6926:7)
 #13     _Timer._createTimerHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io:6934:23)
 #14     _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:37:92)
```

Why doesn't this get catched in the try-catch block? It is thrown in code that is called from within it (even though it isn't shown in the stacktrace).

I expect that I've missed something about how exceptions work in Dart, so I hope you can enlighten me :)

Comment: Could you add the content of the try block please?

Comment: Sorry, but that would be like thousands of lines if I had to include all the code called in relation to the exception... It is a pretty complex web server, where this exception is generated in a module handling the backend of an web based IDE. I hoped that someone could tell me something like that I needed to do something more to catch exceptions in "Futures" or that it has to happen where the Future is created... The exception is generated if I try to read a .png file as text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [Future](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future-class.html), you have to use the [catchError](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) method to deal with exceptions.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: The answer was outdated. I just updated the links where you can find examples.

Comment: Okay but what if the link is outdated again? I recommend posting one of the examples within your answer or create your own

Comment: This article gives a good example of how to use `catchError`: https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-future-exception-handling-catcherror-dosomething

Answer (score 3):

Once you realize what is going on, understanding the issue is pretty simple.

The problem is: the semantics of traditional control flow constructs (`if`, `while`, `try/catch/finally`, `return`) is purely *synchronous*. They expect that the program flows just like its source code flows. Take a look at this:

```
1      try {
2        while (...) {
3          if (...) {
4            doSomething();
5            doSomethingElse();
6          }
7        }
8      } catch (e) {
9        print('oh no, something wrong happen! error: $e');
10     } finally {
11       print('done!');
12     }
```

This program works as a sequence. The line 1 is executed before line 2 which is executed before line 3 etc. Line 5 is executed immediatelly after line 4. Line 11 is executed after line 7, and if an exception happens, line 11 is also executed after line 9. That's what *synchronous* means.

However, synchronous programs are no longer good enough. Event handling is naturally *asynchronous*, and you will find events everywhere -- from user interfaces to highly scalable network servers. So if you write

```
1      try {
2        var text = 'this will be replaced by the content of the file';
3        new File('...').readAsText().then((result) {
4          text = result;
5          doSomethingThatMightCauseAnException(text);
6          print('read file, got $text');
7        });
8        print('invoked file read');
9        return text;
10     } catch (e) {
11       print('error: $e');
12     }
```

you have to understand that you are invoking an asynchronous operation (the `readAsText` method). In this program, line 2 executes after line 1 and line 3 goes after line 2, but line 4 **doesn't** execute after line 3. The file reading is invoked asynchronously (think "in the background") and the program continues. So in this situation, after line 3, you will get directly to line 8. And so the `return` statement on line 9 (which follows line 8) always returns the `'this will be replaced by the content of the file'` text.

Then, the program goes on and on, until it is done (it exits the `main` function). But it *doesn't stop*, because there is some code running "in the background" and there is a handler registered for it (you registered the handler by calling the `then` method). Once the system finishes reading the file, it will call the handler (the anonymous function you passed to the `then` method). Only when there is no handler for some asynchronous invocation registered, the program can stop.

And now, you probably understand that the exception handler on line 10 can *only* catch an error that happens on line 3 (error opening the file). But if an exception happens on line 5, it **can't** be caught on line 10, because that `catch` handler is long gone.

The rest is just a matter of using the API properly. If you work with callbacks, you have to pass an success handler *and* an error handler, if you work with `Future`s, you have to call the `then` method with a success handler *and* the `handleException` method with an error handler.

Comment: This answer of mine just popped up in my list of achievements, so I'd like to point out that this was written _before_ Dart got `async`/`await`. It's still fundamentally true, but with `async`/`await`, the experience is a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too, and I didn't wanted to use `catchError` because I think it is too verbose, so I realized I was missing the `await` before calling the `Future` inside the `try catch`. So, the code must be like that:

```dart
Future<void> doSomething() async {
    try {
        return await Future.error(Exception()); //<-- notice this await!
    } catch (e) {
        debugPrint("Something wrong happended!");
    }
}
```

If the `await` was missed, there's no compile error because the method return is a `Future` too, but the exception must be caught upstream.